# Trying to fix the position of a javascript image tooltip created using dynamicdrive tooltip 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I've searched but can't figure this one out.

**PROBLEM:** The tooltip currently moves relative to the mouse.

**WHAT I WANT:** The tooltip to position 10px below the image i'm rolling over and not follow the cursor.

This is [my site](http://www.barbarasgotsoul.com)

Thanks.

```
    positiontooltip:function($, $tooltip, e){
    var x=e.pageX+this.tooltipoffsets[0], y=e.pageY+this.tooltipoffsets[1]
    var tipw=$tooltip.outerWidth(), tiph=$tooltip.outerHeight(), 
    //x=(x+tipw>$(document).scrollLeft()+$(window).width())? x-tipw-(ddimgtooltip.tooltipoffsets[0]*2) : x
    //y=(y+tiph>$(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height())? $(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-tiph-10 : y
    x=(x+tipw>$(document).scrollLeft()+$(window).width())? x-tipw-(ddimgtooltip.tooltipoffsets[0]*2) : x
    y=(y+tiph>$(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height())? $(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-tiph-10 : y
    $tooltip.css({left:x, top:y})
},
```